# Memory Leak Meteor.http

Tags: node.js, http, memory-leaks, meteor

I'm getting a memory leak from Meteor.http.get when I try to make 5 parallel http requests / second: [gist](https://gist.github.com/sebyx07/11127214)

```
match_ids.forEach(function(match_id){
        var url = self.generateUrl(match_id);
        Meteor.http.get(url, function(err, response){
            if(!err && !response.data.result.error){
                callback(null, response.data.result);
            }else{
                callback(err || response.data.result.error, match_id);
            }
        })
    });
```

It seems to behave the same even if I reduce the rate down to 1 request / second.

```
Meteor.setInterval(function(){
    module.feeder.getMatchesForCarry();
}, 2000);

Meteor.setInterval(function(){
    Meteor.call("TEMP_d2_match_analyzerInsertSampleData", 9, function(err,response){});
}, 10000);
```

Is the source of this problem Node or Meteor?

If i perform 5 requests/sec , in about 5 minutes of running i get 80-100 mega filled

Comment: I am quite interested in this. I think I may be seeing this behaviour on one of my servers with the same scenario (looping http requests). See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158849/meteor-app-deployed-to-digital-ocean-stuck-at-100-cpu-and-oom this doesn't happen locally on my machine. Maybe we can compare notes. What OS version are you running? Node version?

Comment: I'm developing on a lubuntu 14.04, and node version is .10.26. Hopefully before i deploy i will find a way around, and post here how i made it. Also i have posted an issue on [meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2073)

Comment: I made a test now, for 3000 link ,in batches of 10 every 2 seconds. `60mb => 100mb`

Comment: I see the issue you posted. If possible, try to give them a repo with the simplest code demonstrating the issue. Otherwise they may not look at it if the code is too complex. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and Node 0.10.25. It's about as close as I could get to my dev machine. I just got profiling going so I am going to run more tests.

Comment: Is this issue still present in 2018?

Comment: @Jankapunkt no.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the code that you shared. Your memory leak, if that's indeed what you're observing, is in other places.